Prove there exist matrices $S$ and $T$ such that $B=S(A+T)S^{-1} -T$ iff $\text{tr}(A)=\text{tr}(B)$.
So this problem appeared on a list called "Matrix Problems", meant to be like training for competition-level maths. The whole problem goes like this: Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices with complex entries. Prove there exists an invertible matrix $S$ and another matrix $T$ such that $B=S(A+T)S^{-1} -T$ if and only if $\text{tr}(A)=\text{tr}(B)$.
I didn't have any trouble solving the left-to-right part of the implication since it is easy to see that:
$B + T = S(A+T)S^{-1}$ $\implies$ $\text{tr}(B+T) = \text{tr}(A+T)$ $\implies$ $\text{tr}(B)=\text{tr}(A)$ .
But supposing traces are equal and then proving there exists another matrix that makes $B+T$ similar to $A+T$ is probably not so trivial. Of course, similar matrices have the same traces, but the converse does not always hold. I hope the idea here is to define $T$ in such a way that it "fixes" other requirements for the matrices to be similar, but I don't really remember any theorem that can make me be sure of that. I also don't know if the "complex entries" could help here, maybe to reach a Jordan form or something, since the trace, in this case, equals the sum of eigenvalues, but I couldn't find anything with this.
Any solution or idea is appreciated.

Could you provide a link to the "Matrix Problems" list? I want to see other problems like this.

Let $P$ be an invertible matrix and define
\begin{align*}
B'&=P(B-A)P^{-1},\\
S'&=PSP^{-1},\\
T'&=P(A+T)P^{-1}.
\end{align*}
The equation $B=S(A+T)S^{-1}-T$ is then equivalent to
$$
B'=S'T'S'^{-1}-T'.\tag{1}
$$
Since $B-A$ has a zero trace, we may choose $P$ such that $B'$ has a zero diagonal. Now take $S'$ to be any diagonal matrix with $n$ different nonzero elements. Equation $(1)$ is solved by $t_{ij}'=\left(\dfrac{s_{ii}'}{s_{jj}'}-1\right)^{-1}b_{ij}'$ for all $i\ne j$. (The diagonal elements of $T'$ can be arbitrary.) Hence the original equation is solved by $S=P^{-1}S'P$ and $T=P^{-1}T'P-A$.
